# CSV file parsing in Bash

Tags: bash, csv

I have a CSV file with sample entries given below. What I want is to write a Bash script to read the CSV file line by line and put the first entry e.g `005` in one variable and the IP `192.168.10.1` in another variable, that I need to pass to some other script.

```
005,192.168.10.1
006,192.168.10.109
007,192.168.10.12
008,192.168.10.121
009,192.168.10.123
```

Comment: Is the file basic csv, or do you plan advanced string literal stuff?

Comment: Is there a question here? I don't see one. What's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 3):

A more efficient approach, without the need to fork `cut` each time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS=, read -r field1 field2; do
    # do something with $field1 and $field2
done < file.csv
```

The gains can be quite substantial for large files.

Comment: Yeah, much better than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it with GNU tools :

```
while read line; do
    echo $line | cut -d, -f1-2 --output-delimiter=' ' | xargs your_command
done < your_input.csv
```

`while read line; do [...]; done < your_input.csv` will read your file line by line.
For each line, we will `cut` it to its first two fields (separated by commas since it's a CSV) and pass them separated by spaces to `xargs` which will in turn pass as parameters to `your_command`.

Comment: This will not chop off the comma and thus the two fields will be interpreted as one parameter by the command.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem right, I should have tested it with commas rather than spaces. Do you think using `--output-delimiter=' '` would be enough to solve this?

Comment: it looks like it works well with `--output-delimiter=' '`

Answer (score 0):

If this is a **very simple csv** file with no string literals, etc. you can simply use `head` and `cut`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    id_field=$(cut -d',' -f 1 <<<"$line") #here 005 for the first line
    ip_field=$(cut -d',' -f 2 <<<"$line") #here 192.168.0.1 for the first line
    #do something with $id_field and $ip_field
done < file.csv
```

The program works as follows: we use `cut -d','` to obtain the first and second field of that line. We wrap this around a `while read line` and use *I/O redirection* to feed the file to the `while` loop.

Of course you substitute `file.csv` with the name of the file you want to process, and you can use other variable names than the ones in this sample.

Comment: How to run this script is loop to do the above for every line in the CSV. because there are more than hundred lines that i want to do the same as above

Comment: @Robin: ah, somehow I missed you want to do this for every line and I assumed you only wanted to process the first line. See edit.

Comment: This is insanely inefficient.

Comment: @chepner: yeah well usually you don't write bash scripts for raytracing (it has been done by someone, I know) nor to do dynamic programming on the subsum problem. We're talking about 100 lines that have to be processed... For performance one uses a (statically) typed compiled language with strong compiler optimizations.